# Find out which droppable the a draggable is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI to perform some drag and drops. I'm trying to find out what droppable a draggable is in.

Can anyone help? Here's my code.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        console.log(event);
        // I need the element which this draggable is correct in.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Patricia has it slightly the wrong way round. Ive forked their jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SQegt/) but the essence is in getting the id of the item dropped into

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
         alert($(this).attr("id"));  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you'll need to catch that in the droppables drop callback.

```
$('#draggable').draggable();
$('#droppable').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
         alert($(this).attr("id"));  
    }
});
```

here's a look at this fiddle to play around with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vsC4/

edit:  oops, that's the id of the dragged element! you want where it landed!  which is easy!  I've edited the script here in the answer to show that.

take a look at the draggable and droppable documentation for more info about how they work:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/